# FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, scipy, save

I receive a warning that is

> "C:\Users\el\Anaconda3\envs\Py3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\miobase.py:414:
>   FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional
>   indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`.
>   In the future this will be interpreted as an array index,
>   `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a
>   different result.
>
> ```
> arr[empties] = ' '".
> ```

Although already, I used "sio.savemat" to save the output of codes without any warning, now it gives me a warning. How can I solve it?

Also, scipy = 1.1.0

```
import scipy.io as sio
sio.savemat(os.path.join("D:\Codes", "num.mat"), {'num': num})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is being issued by NumPy version 1.15 or higher, and is being generated because of code in scipy version 1.1.0. It will be [fixed in Scipy version 1.2.0](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9086). Notice the [change to miobase.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/8944/files#diff-4cbb3d2651d341051f8658d4c0002c6b).

As long as you continue using your current versions of NumPy and SciPy, you have nothing to worry about. In the future, when you upgrade your NumPy (to when the behavior of non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing has changed), then be sure to also upgrade your SciPy to at least version 1.2.0.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, I searched and not found it in anaconda. (Scipy 1.2.0 is not released yet!) :    https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scipy                 So now, It cannot be solved.

Comment: If the FutureWarning really bothers you, you could edit your C:\Users\el\Anaconda3\envs\Py3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\miobase.py file on line 414 by changing `arr[empties] = ' '` to `arr[tuple(empties)] = ' '`. That should silence the FutureWarning when using `sio.savemat`.

Comment: Thank you for replying.