# Incompatible scipy and numpy versions

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am trying to install a python package "ezLncPred" which requires a numpy version of 1.15 in my python3.8. While installing it tells that this version of numpy is not compatible with my SciPy version of 1.7.3. I have to upgrade it to numpy1.2 for it.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: If you have to use `ezLncPred` with `NumPy` version **1.15**, so you have to downgrade your SciPy version to a compatible one.

Comment: How can i know which version of scipy is compatible with Numpy1.15 ?

Comment: You must search about it. Perhaps `1.2.0` or `1.2.1` be that version you need based on one of [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817582/13394817).